# How to show a div on focus out using jQuery/CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="box">
    <input type="text" value="url" />
    <span class="add-btn"> + </span>
</div>
```

On click of add button or plus mark, another box should be dynamic added.  how to achieve it in jquery.

Comment: check out jquery [blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) and jquery [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.blur()`](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) to trigger when a field loses focus:

```
$('.box input[type=text]').blur(function () {
    //Whatever you want to do.
});
```

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8xmyk23/)

Showing the div depends a bit on how you implement it.

The easiest way is to add another div with an ID, and set the style to hidden like this:

```
<div class="box">
    <input type="text" value="url" />
</div>
<div id="secondDiv" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" value="other field" />
</div>
```

And then use the [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) to show it:

```
$('.box input[type=text]').blur(function () {
    $('#secondDiv').show();
});
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fyvmtq57/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.input-1').focusout(function() {
  $('.input-2').show();
});
```

```css
.input-2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <input type="text" value="url" class="input-1" />
  <input type="text" value="url" class="input-2" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you could do:

```
$(".box").on("focusout", "input", function(){
    $(".box").append("<br/><input/>");
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsv7joqk/)

Answer (score 0):

Add two text boxes by default, but set one of them as hidden. On the focus out of the first text box just remove the hidden property of second one

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="url" id=txt1/>
<input type="text" value="url" id=txt2 hidden/>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#txt1').blur(function(){

$('#txt2').removeAttr('hidden')

})

})
```